# Magento 2: Problem in installing installation?

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

I'm installing Magento 2 using composer that I have downloaded from GitHub. While installing I'm asked with the username from repo.magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login to https://marketplace.magento.com and go to Marketplace tab.

Click on My Access Keys and then click on Magento 2 tab.

Click on Create a New Access Key button, provide name and click on Generate New button.

Then you can use public key as username​ and private key as password to install Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

These are access keys which you can get from Magento Marketplace.

Public-key is username and Private-key is password.

If you already have keys, use the Public Key as your user name and the Private Key as your password.

To create a new key pair, click Create a New Access Key.

Here is what you need: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html